# Combine 2 pandas dataframes according to boolean Vector

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is the following:
Let's say I have two dataframes with same number of columns in pandas like for instance:

```
A= 1 2
   3 4 
   8 9
```

and

```
B= 7 8
   4 0
```

And also one boolean vector of length exactly num of rows from A + num of B rows = 5 , with the same number of `1`s as num of rows in B which means two `1`s in this example.
Let's say `Bool= 0 1 0 1 0`.

My goal is then to merge A and B into a bigger dataframe called C such that the rows of B corresponds to the 1s in Bool , so with this example it would give me:

```
C= 1 2
   7 8
   3 4 
   4 0
   8 9
```

Do you know how to do this please?
If you know how this would help me tremendously.
Thanks for your reading.

Comment: You mentioned in a now-deleted post that these answers had helped you. Please mark as accepted whichever one that was most relevant to your question. That's what makes the site go round.

Answer (score 8):

One option is to create an empty data frame with the expected shape and then fill the values from *A* and *B* in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize a data frame with the same data types as A thanks to @piRSquared
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((A.shape[0] + B.shape[0], A.shape[1])), dtype=A.dtypes)
Bool = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]).astype(bool)

df.loc[Bool,:] = B.values
df.loc[~Bool,:] = A.values

df
#   0   1
#0  1   2
#1  7   8
#2  3   4
#3  4   0
#4  8   9
```

Comment: That's clever !

Comment: Brilliant!  Both of you!

Comment: Because your answer tends toward being more generalizable, I'd consider using a `astype(A.dtypes)` somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a pandas-only solution that reindexes the original dataframes and then concatenates them:

```
Bool = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool) 
B.index = Bool[ Bool].index
A.index = Bool[~Bool].index
pd.concat([A,B]).sort_index() # sort_index() is not really necessary
#   0  1
#0  1  2
#1  7  8
#2  3  4
#3  4  0
#4  8  9
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Both of you!

Answer (score 4):

The following approach will generalize to larger groups than 2.  Starting from

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[8,9]])    
B = pd.DataFrame([[7,8],[4,0]])    
C = pd.DataFrame([[9,9],[5,5]])
bb = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0])
```

we can use

```
pd.concat([A, B, C]).iloc[bb.rank(method='first')-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives

```
In [269]: pd.concat([A, B, C]).iloc[bb.rank(method='first')-1].reset_index(drop=True)
Out[269]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  7  8
2  3  4
3  4  0
4  9  9
5  5  5
6  8  9
```

---

This works because when you use `method='first'`, it ranks the values by their values in order and then by the order in which they're seen.  This means that we get things like

```
In [270]: pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 0]).rank(method='first')
Out[270]: 
0    4.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    5.0
4    3.0
dtype: float64
```

which is exactly (after subtracting one) the iloc order in which we want to select the rows.